# Severe latency in Solana web3 app WebSocket call

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, phantom, web3.js, websocket, latency

I'm working on a Solana web3 app using the `@solana/wallet-adapter-react` package. The function calls a contract that modifies some accounts. It then takes the transaction ID, awaits confirmation, (with the default confirmation strategy), and then re-fetches those accounts with the updated data. However, we are seeing massive slowness with this request. The call to update seems to wait until a particular WebSockets request is terminated. The status we're getting back is `HTTP 101 Switching Protocols`. I'm not sure why the confirmation is waiting on this request, or what is actually going on via WebSockets. The HAR file showing the WebSockets interaction, including the calls made over the socket, is attached. I redacted from this HAR file to remove some sensitive information, but if there is a bit of data that is necessary to debug, such as the actual ID of the transaction, I have the original and can supply it. Does anyone have experience with this issue? Is it possible to tell what's going on, or why it takes so long to confirm this transaction before re-fetching? [HAR file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9sgy8w9meupe9yt/websockets-request.har?dl=0)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because there is so much detail missing, particularly the source code that triggers all of these network requests. If this is still a problem, let's get more detail!